# pubnub processing/java for a noob

Tags: java, processing, pubnub

I am using processing (IE, JAVA) to publish via pubnub. After reading nearly all the simple startup documentation, I am at a loss. My code is running, but not publishing anything. I have the libraries installed correctly I believe, but no messages are published via my keys.

I know I am just not understanding something really simple here, but I have no idea what that might be. I added a 5s delay to ensure everything finishes before setup stops as suggested in other posts. Right now it runs, but no messages show up in the app with those keys(which I replaced below). All the examples are way over my head and not helping my poor noob brain.

I also setup the same basic code in Python which also runs but does not actually publish the message. Leading me to think I am just missing something very fundamental.

In the end, I want to push data from a UI to an online [real-time dashboard](https://www.pubnub.com/developers/eon/chart/spline/). This seems trivially easy, but it is a complete black hole.

Here is my code (it's basically just a copy and paste from the startup code):

```
import com.pubnub.api.*;
import org.json.*;

Pubnub pubnub = new Pubnub("PUBKEY", "SUBKEY");

void setup()
{
  try {
    pubnub.subscribe("NSFPhaseII", new Callback() {
      @Override
      public void connectCallback(String channel, Object message) {
        pubnub.publish("NSFPhaseII", "Hello from the PubNub Java SDK", new Callback() {});
      }

      @Override
      public void disconnectCallback(String channel, Object message) {
        System.out.println("SUBSCRIBE : DISCONNECT on channel:" + channel
          + " : " + message.getClass() + " : "
          + message.toString());
      }

      public void reconnectCallback(String channel, Object message) {
        System.out.println("SUBSCRIBE : RECONNECT on channel:" + channel
          + " : " + message.getClass() + " : "
          + message.toString());
      }

      @Override
      public void successCallback(String channel, Object message) {
        System.out.println("SUBSCRIBE : " + channel + " : "
          + message.getClass() + " : " + message.toString());
      }

      @Override
      public void errorCallback(String channel, PubnubError error) {
        System.out.println("SUBSCRIBE : ERROR on channel " + channel
          + " : " + error.toString());
      }
    });
  } 
  catch (PubnubException e) {
    System.out.println(e.toString());
  }

  delay(5000);
  println("done");
}
```

Comment: I do not recognize this code from any of our samples but we have lots of references out there. Can you provide a link to where you got this code from?

Comment: And any error messages? Any other descriptions about what is not working for you? Kind of difficult understand the issue based on the info provided.

Comment: This code is from the Java SDK page [link](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/java-se-java/pubnub-java-sdk)

Comment: I don't get any errors actually. This is printed: SUBSCRIBE : NSFPhaseII : class java.lang.String : Hello from the PubNub Java SDK
done. Nothing happens. IE, no message is published to the app/channel.

Comment: @Murenrb What do you expect to be published?

Comment: Yeah... this is exactly my point. I feel like what I think Pubnub does and what it actually does are way different. I thought that the string "Hello from the PubNub Java SDK" would get published to the channel "NSFPhaseII". All the PubNub documentation shows variables flying all over from one app to the other... I suspect that takes way more code than this, but I can't seem to find any documentation that highlights what I am missing. Right now I would just like to start with a single message getting published to my app.

Comment: First, it doesn't take very much code to to publish and subscribe with PubNub. I want to know how your code is being invoked. It doesn't even look like fully valid Java (been away from java since early version 7 though). But where is your class declaration? It's just a method called `setup`. How is setup being called? Is it being called? Can you debug into this method and see where it is failing, if at all? Is this Scala or some other Java language variant?

Comment: I would recommend checking out [University of PubNub](https://www.pubnub.com/developers/university/) to get a very basic understanding of PubNub Although code examples are JavaScript, it the concepts are the same on all SDKs.

Comment: @CraigConover I am using Processing so that is why the structure is not what you are expecting. I read through a fair amount of documentation at the University of PubNub, but apparently I am still not getting it. I will give it some more time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answering my own question here.

It turns out this code has been working all along. I setup two processing sketches in a publish subscribe type setup and could clearly see that one was receiving the publishes from the other.

Then, when I checked on pubnub, the messages registered in my account. I am not really sure if the messages were registering in my account all along and just not updating or if they took some time, but I believe it was working all along and I was just not waiting long enough to see the messages register online.

Like I said. Noobs...